# Google cloud endpoint framework 2.0 issue at iOS client side

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform

I am getting operation could not be completed error when calling a service. At server we are using Google cloud EndPoints framework 2.0. I have generated the service using https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client.

Answer (score 0):

As per the document “[Migrating to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0 for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/migrating#currently_excluded_features)”, the JSON-RPC protocol, required for legacy iOS clients, is one of the features that are currently not available for Endpoints v2 and the recommendation is to use the “[Google APIs Objective-C Client Library for REST APIs](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest)”, which replaced the “[Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client)” that you are using and was deprecated as per indicated in the link that you mentioned.